# Why do we read about forbidden relationships on Yom Kippur

Tags: torah-reading, yom-kippur, mincha-afternoon-prayer, arayot

Part of the torah reading on Yom Kippur is the list of forbidden intimate relationships in Vayikra 18. I would like to know why we read that section of the torah on Yom Kippur

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76815/759

Answer (score 2):

In the Shulchan Aruch, O"C, 622:2, the Taz explains (my loose translation) that [sub 4] Tosafot explain that the connection is that in the same waay that we are enjoined from uncovering nakedness, Hashem will not uncover our sins, then he mentions that since man is most drawn to these sins, we need extra reminders on the day which is most awesome and most engraved in our hearts. These are also mentioned in the Be'eir Heitev who cites [Talmud Megilla 31a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=31&format=text) and the Tosafot there which says that the reminder is needed because the women are adorned for the Kavod of the day so they must be cautioned that no one should stumble on their account in these areas.

Comment: http://mechon-mamre.org/i/2213.htm#11

Comment: לְפִי שֶׁהָעֲרָיוֹת עֲבֵרָה מְצוּיָה, שֶׁנַּפְשׁוֹ שֶׁל אָדָם מְחַמְּדָתָן וְיִצְרוֹ תּוֹקְפוֹ. רַשִׁ"י. וּכְלוֹמַר וְכָל מִי שֶׁנִּכְשַׁל בְּאַחַת מֵהֶן יִזְכֹּר וְיִכָּלֵם וְיַחְזֹר בִּתְשׁוּבָה. הָרַמְבַּ"ם:  yikar To YT